# How to remove multiple lines from a file with python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to remove lines from a file using this code:

```py
with open('example_file', 'r') as file:
    file_content = file.readlines()
file.close()
            
with open('example_file', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in file_content:
        if line.strip("\n") != 'example_line_1':
            new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

This works well for one line but how can I remove other (multiple) lines as well?

Comment: Your question is not clear.
What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: why do you frist read the whole file ? do you want to remove same content or other ( a list of contents) contents ?

Comment: I have a file that contains multiple lines. I want to edit this file using a python script, adding or removing lines. So far it's easy to remove one specific line but how can I do this for more than one line? Actually to delete the lines

Comment: I'm reading the whole file since I want to remove lines based on specific input, so I want to have all the content of the file available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using `and`.

```py
...

with open('example_file', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in file_content:
        currentLine = line.strip("\n")
        if currentLine != 'example_line_1' and currentLine != 'example_line_2':
            new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

but that gets too big, too fast. You could also use an array with words you wish to remove from a line and then just check if the current line consists of any of those words:

```py
...
words = ["example_line_1", "example_line_2", "foobar"]
with open('example_file', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in file_content:
        currentLine = line.strip("\n")
        if currentLine not in words:
            new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

Comment: Remembering that with these methods only work if any undesired word is the sole content of each line. To remove any lines who may contain any unwanted word, regardless of other contents you should iterate over each word on each line and then compare it to your undesired words.